# CSS replace text in a javascript generated table by an image

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have on my club webpage a score tables where i want to change the text that indicates a club into the logo of this club. for example RHI,BRL,MAM has to become an logo image.
I can not figure out how to do this in CSSor javascript. Does anybody know the answer?

the code that generates the tables is:

```
<h2>Men's games</h2>
<div class="pb-dynamic" id="block-main-men">
<p><img src="//www.pointbench.com/pointbench/img/pb-loading-1.gif" /></p>
</div>

<h2>Women's games</h2>
<div class="pb-dynamic" id="block-main-women">
<p><img src="//www.pointbench.com/pointbench/img/pb-loading-1.gif" /></p>
</div>

<!-- Include JS script to do the job, block definition(s) and main function call --><script src="//stats.pointbench.com/pointbench/js/pb-update-ex.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[// ><!--


blockdefs =
[
{
  leagueid: 'bel/29/2021',
  blocktype: 'team-games',
  target: 'block-main-men',
  teamid: '413'
},
{
  leagueid: 'bel/30/2021',
  blocktype: 'team-games',
  target: 'block-main-women',
  teamid: '207'
}
];

PBShowBlocks( blockdefs );


//--><!]]>
</script><!-- End --></div>
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more information on what you have tried and be more specific on your problem is. It will be tough to answer the question as it's given now.

Answer (score 0):

If I use the following CSS code (in this case a color but could also be a image)

```
td[class="team"] {
        color: red;
    }
```

The whole columns turns red. But I want that only the ones with 'RHI' in it turns red.

That I cannot figure out

Comment: While I appreciate the updated information, could you please use the "edit" link below the text of your question to add the information there, this space is for answers and this - obviously - isn't an answer, it's clarification.